# Unable to install apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

When I want to download the update with command `sudo apt-get update` some files downloaded but after some percentage it says

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources
 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Comment: utopic is 14.10. This is not 14.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

Trying switching your mirror.

You can use something like "Software sources" or "Software & Updates". You should see a tab called Ubuntu Software. On that tab is a drop-down list titled "Download from". Change your mirror to somewhere else that is close to you, or if you have already changed the location change it to main USA server). This works for me when I have trouble with apt-get updating properly.